# Python 3.7.4 urllib issue in request.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, request, urllib

Python **3.7.4** `urllib` has an issue in `request.py` - *MemoryError* has thrown because of 
`_load_windows_store_certs` - in my case it happened after requesting different *https* URL many times, memory consumption was increasing until program execution failed.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: fixed by updating Python version from **3.7.4** to **3.8.1** (released in *Dec. 18, 2019*)

Read more in [Python changelog](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html)